# Assigning image using random assigns the same image to all JButtons

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

Made a simple Dice throwing test from my code, in an attempt to find why the same image is displayed for every JButton. I have a feeling that the values are not being properly read by the program and so it assigns the same image to all the JButtons.

Test Class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    JButton[] pic = new JButton[5];
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton throwDice = new JButton("Throw");
    ImageIcon img;

    Die[] dieH = new Die[5];
    Dice dice = new Dice();

    Test(String title) {
        super(title);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        components();
        throwHandle();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test("Test");
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void components() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            pic[i] = new JButton("");
            pic[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
            panel.add(pic[i]);
        }
        panel.add(throwDice);
    }

    public void throwHandle() {
        throwDice.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dieH = dice.roll();

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    pic[i].setIcon(dieH[i].getDieImage());
                    System.out.println(dieH[i].getValue());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Die Class

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Die {

    int faceValue;
    ImageIcon img;

    public ImageIcon getDieImage() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImage() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        img = new ImageIcon("./src/images/" + i + ".png");
        }
    }

    public void setValue(int v) {
        this.faceValue = v;
        setImage();
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return faceValue;
    }
}
```

Dice Class

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {

    Die[] diceArray = new Die[6];

    int min = 1, max = 6;

    public Dice() {
        for (int i = 0; i < diceArray.length; i++) {
        diceArray[i] = new Die();
        diceArray[i].setValue(i + 1);
        }
     }

    public Die[] roll() {
        Random rm = new Random();
        Die[] roll = new Die[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int newRandom = rm.nextInt((max - min) + 1);
            roll[i] = diceArray[newRandom];
            System.out.println(roll[i].getValue());
        }

        return roll;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's examine the following code:

```
public class Die {

    int faceValue;
    ImageIcon img;
```

So, a Die has a unique face value, and a unique image

```
    public ImageIcon getDieImage() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImage() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            img = new ImageIcon("./src/images/" + i + ".png");
        }
```

So, you loop from 0 to 6, and at each iteration, you replace the previous image by a new one. This is equivalent to `img = new ImageIcon("./src/images/6.png");`. Note also that the image doesn't depend on the face favleu of the die.

```
    }

    public void setValue(int v) {
        this.faceValue = v;
        setImage();
```

This sets the face value of the die, and it then sets the image, but the image doesn't depend on the face value at all.

```
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return faceValue;
    }
}
```

So, basically, `setImage()` needs to use the face value, and set the image based on the face value. It should also be private: you don't want anyone to change the image of a dice without changing its face value.

```
private void setImage() {
    img = new ImageIcon("./src/images/" + this.faceValue + ".png");
}
```

Comment: I see, I passed in faceValue to the setImage setter, I believe this is correct as it does now change the images. I may need to modify the value a little as the faceValue seems to be 1 less than what is actually printed.